# How to change useEffect in class component React native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, components

I want to rewrite my code from function to class, but I got stuck with useEffect function.

I have an array that updates after adding new element, but function countTotal starts to work after update.
So, 
1) open App myArray has two objects, Total sum = 0 (but should be 300)
2) add new object with sum 100 into myArray three objects, Total sum = 300 (should be 400)

```
export default class Home extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            total:0,
            expenses:[
                { key: '1', sum: '100',  date: '12 April 2020' },
                { key: '2', sum: '200', date: '17 April 2020' },
            ],
        }
        this.submitHandler = this.submitHandler.bind(this);
        this.countTotal = this.countTotal.bind(this);
    }

    countTotal(){
        const totalSum = this.state.expenses.reduce((prev,next) => prev + Number(next.sum),0);
        this.setState({total: totalSum})
    }

    submitHandler (sum, date) {
        const key = Math.random().toString();
        const obj = {'key':key, 'sum':sum, 'date':date};

        this.setState(prevState => ({ 
                expenses: [obj, ...prevState.expenses]}))
        countTotal()  
    };  
    render(){
        return (
            <DismissKeyboard>
              <View style={styles.container}>

                <View style={styles.content}>
                  <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.showList}>
                    <Costs costs={this.state.total}  />
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>


                <View style={styles.list}>
                  <FlatList
                    data={this.state.expenses}
                    renderItem={({ item }) => (
                      <ListCosts item={item} pressHandler={this.pressHandler} />
                    )}
                  />
                </View>

              </DismissKeyboard>

          );
        }
    }
```

So it worked using it

```
useEffect= (()=> {
    const totalSum = expenses.reduce((prev,next) => prev + Number(next.sum),0);
    setTotal(totalSum)
    console.log(totalSum)
    } [expenses]);
```

I tried to add componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate but nothing.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the code that you posted seems to be working fine. I have created codesandbox url 
https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-shaw-toe9p

Only difference in the code above between the functional component and class component is

Here in useEffect gets called every time expenses is changed, but componentDidMount will get called only once after the component is mounted. So we have to create a function and call that function everytime the expenses is updated

```
setState(updater, [callback])
```

[setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

so when calling setState, we can pass the callback function to the setState and update the total value

Count total should be given in callback, because the setState is Asynchronous

```
    this.setState(prevState => ({ 
            expenses: [obj, ...prevState.expenses]}), countTotal)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Yes, my code works ... a part of them.  I will read about callback. I've change my question a bit.

Comment: I have updated the answer, can you check. Added callback in setState @Vova

Comment: thanks! It works. Maybe you know how to show this sumTotal here -> open App myArray has two objects, Total sum = 0  (but should be 300). Because it worked only with componentDidMount ...

Comment: I add componentDidMount with the same code as countTotal, not sure if it's right, but it works well. Thanks again